# inserting tab box in section tag resulting another tag dis aligned... how to fix?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i'm trying to insert this tab box in my section tag.. from this website http://www.9bitstudios.com/2012/11/create-a-responsive-tab-box-using-jquery-and-css/

source code download link: http://www.9bitstudios.com/demos/blog/tab-box/tab-box.zip

here is my html code

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Librarian's corner</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/nav-menu.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/body.css">

</head>
 <body >

 <div class="big-wrapper">
 <div class="form-nav-menu">
 <nav>

    <ul>
        <li><a id="active" href="adduser.html">ADD USER</a></li>
        <li><a  class="in-active" href="#">EDIT USER</a></li>
        <li><a  class="in-active" href="#">DELETE USER</a></li>
        <li><a  class="in-active" href="#"> VIEW USER</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
 </div>

  <header>
<h1>The Librarian's corner</h1>
</header>



  <section>

  > insert tab  box here <

 </section>



 <footer>
 <h1>this is footer</h1>
  </footer>
   </body>
  </html>
```

and my css code filename: nav-menu.css

```
 * {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

 html {
width: 100%;
display: -webkit-box;
-webkit-box-pack: center;
background: orange;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;

 }
 body {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;

}

header {
width: 100%;


 background: rgba(0, 0, 12, 1); /* Fallback */

 background-color: rgba(12, 12, 12, 0.5);

 margin: 0;

  }
 header h1 {
text-align: center;
line-height: 400px;
z-index: 99;
color: #fff;
font-size: 50px;
font-family: Comic Sans, Comic Sans MS, cursive;
text-shadow: rgb(3, 3, 3) 4px 4px 4px;
height: auto;
}

 section {
height: auto;
background: white;
width: 100%;
margin-top: 0px;
}


footer {
height: 150px;
background: black;
width: 100%;
margin-top: 0px;
}


.form-nav-menu {

z-index: 99;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
display: -webkit-box;
-webkit-box-pack: center;

  }

.form-nav-menu nav {
width: 100%;
height: 70px;
}
.form-nav-menu nav ul{
width: 100%;
height: 70px;
list-style-type: none;
}
.form-nav-menu nav ul li{
height: 70px;
width: 120px;
display: inline-block;
float: right;
}
```

the problem is when i trying to insert the css tab box code for the tab box located in section tag, the footer background dis align...

im wondering why, why the footer background dis aligned.. my body background is orange and the footer is black...  as we can see, the black color is in the top..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may need to add a min-height to your "section" tag since you've added that container:

```
section {
height: auto;
**min-height:300px;**
background: white;
width: 100%;
margin-top: 0px;
}
```